# Security group for s3 hosted website making http requests

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Let’s assume that I have a S3 hosted website. Aside from that I have an EC2 that would be to receive http requests from that website. Is there a way that I can set up a security group so that that EC2 can only receive http requests from that website? I know that if the website was hosted on another EC2 I could this vos the IP address or a load balancer, I’m just not sure how to go about it in the S3 website case.

Comment: There is actually a conceptual problem with what you are asking.  Request traffic to a server does not come "from" a web site.  It comes from a browser that is rendering the site, and all you normally have to work with is the browser's assertions (e.g. `Referer` and `Origin`) that it really is rendering that particular site... but these assertions have no guarantee of authenticity. Whether that mechanism is sufficient depends on what kind of content you are trying to protect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a website on S3 you will have all Static front-end Contents being served (Just like having a pure HTML/CSS/Javascript website with no Webserver on your local Machine). Means all the calls, XHRs or embedded resource pointing to your EC2 instance are requests which are **generated** by **visitors Browsers** with Network **Source of their IP** with the Origin of "S3 or If you place a CloudFront on S3 it will be CloudFront as Origin in HTTP Headers) communicating with the Destination Target of EC2 (Where you have your WebServer serving on port 80or443). There is no SG that could be applied on the Bucket. However, S3 Buckets can be configured with a Policy to white-list certain IPs address to access Bucket Content and subsequently the Static Web content hosted on it. You can Also enforce CORS policy and have conditions to check Referees and Origins.

Putting aside the Bucket Level Policy, IP White listing, CORS and Condition Restrictions If you serve your Web S3 Bucket from a CloudFront Distribution you can apply GEOIP restriction Rules at the CloudFront level as well.

Just in case if say like you have an API server on EC2 which is going to be called by your CloudFront Domain you can Apply some access control at both CloudFront and EC2 Web level to enforce tightened CORS policies. I.e. Other Websites on the Internet can not Hijack your API service or do CSRF attacks(again as a Browser Level Protection Only).